# Whats the correct way to write nginx configuration for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, configuration, localhost

I have a problem with configuring my wordpress nginx settings.
This is my nginx configuraton

```
server {
        listen                  80;
        server_name             wordpress.project;
        access_log              /var/log/nginx/wordpress.project/access.log;
        error_log               /var/log/nginx/wordpress.project/error.log;
        root                    /var/www/wordpress.project;

        location / {
                index app_dev.php;
                if (-f $request_filename) {
                break;
                }
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                #fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index                   index.php;
                fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
                include                         fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

Hosts file is set as `127.0.0.1 wordpress.project`

Permissions of folders are set

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /var/www/wordpress.project
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wordpress.project
```

And symbolic link is set

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpess.project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpess.project
```

And there is still an error when i try accessing wordpress.project saying

> File not found

Project has classic wordpress structure of files
[image]
Is this correct configuration for wordpress in nginx and if its not what is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
server
{
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/wordpress.project;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name your_domain.com;

        location / {
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Please restart Nginx after changing the configuration (sudo service nginx restart)

Comment: Can you please share the directory and file structure of your project?

Comment: You have it now in the description of question

Comment: Try server name as.
server_name 127.0.0.1;
Add port if you are using any

Comment: Try commenting 
try_files $uri =404;
In last location block and check 404 is coming or not

Comment: Now it just says File not found

Comment: Please refer this also
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Try this for last location block

"location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}"

sudo service php5-fpm restart sudo service nginx restart